# Appcache files not updated

Tags: c#, javascript, caching, offline-caching, offlineapps

### Circumstances

I'm building a webapp that will be used offline but will also be updated regularily when it's used online. I'm invalidating the manifest server side by adding a comment containing a tstamp and then reload the page automatically via JS as soon as that change is detected. That worked perfectly fine until now.

---

### Problem

The above process is still executed completely, but for some reason, everytime the browser tries to **fetch the new files**, **only old ressources are loaded**. So the update progress is definitly firing and working (i can tell from chromes console), but it seems that the files requested during the process are retrieved from the **browser cache** (!= appcache).

This occurs **even if I deleted the browser cache before**. Also, I'm already using **several anti-cache metas** and **changed IIS's invalidation header** for immediate invalidation.

---

### Additional Info

When I delete the application cache manually the problem is solved. But it will reoccur after some time (unfortunately i have no idea that triggers this)

Answer (score 0):

Seems you want the cache to be used when offline, but not when you're online? I don't think it does that magically...

Comment: No. I've got an update logic which works fine as mentioned above. The problem is, that the files are, when they should be updated from the server, are actually just transfered from the **browser cache** into the **offline cache** (at least thats what chromes console tells me)

Comment: with the limited information I have I would say you should be checking your HTTP headers etc, any other suggests I would need more info.

Comment: I will check them. Which other infos do you want?

Comment: I just figured out that the console isn't showing any files beeing downloaded via the appcache progress. This means i can not know if the ressources are really loaded from cache. Also, can you tell me how to check the http headers without that console?